# You mean (like) a therapist?

Tags: idiomatic-language

A: Have you talked to someone about it?

B: You mean (like) a therapist?

I believe I've heard 'like' being used in similar sentences, but what would adding it do to the question here? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

There are at least two possibilities, either of which could be the case in your exchange.

- It's just a meaningless [filler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_(linguistics)). "You mean, like, a therapist?"
- It's the standard preposition (prepositional meaning 1a in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/like)). "You mean [someone] like a therapist?"

In practice, for your example, the sense of the reply is basically the same in either interpretation.

Answer (score -1):

Like can be (over)used to provide emphasis.

As an example, in the game `Phoenix Wright: Ace Attorney – Justice for All`, case 2 `Reunion, and Turnabout`, the character `Ini Miney` says `like` about once each 5 words.