# What was the weather like? vs What was the weather?

Tags: questions

What's the difference in their meaning? Does the word "like" change something? If I understand it, both sentences ask about the same. In that case, is "like" usage a personal habit?

> What was the weather like?
>
> What was the weather?

Comment: The second is incorrect.  It should be "How was the weather?"

Comment: @BillyKerr, no it is perfectly acceptable to say, "What was the weather?" E.G., Alice: "I was seasick on the boat." Bill: "What was the weather?"

Comment: @DrMoishePippik That doesn't make any sense to me.  It's like the difference between "What was the banana like?" and "What was the banana?". The answer to the first is "Delicious".  The answer to the second is "It was a fruit, but now it's in my stomach".

Comment: In the sentence. "Go!' the subject is understood. In the example, to a native English speaker, it is understood that it is the *weather during the boat trip*.

Comment: That is a false analogy.  "Go!" is simply the imperative form of the verb to go.  The subject is generally omitted before an imperative.  This is a completely different construction from the question being asked here. Oh, and BTW. I am a native English speaker.  It may be acceptable in your part of the world, but not in mine.

Comment: You enjoyed watching a particular TV show. You describe the plot to your friend. Your friend then asks "**What was the show?**” They could have also said “**What's the name of the show?**” If your friend wants to know if the TV show is any good, they'd ask: "**What's/was the show like?**”

Comment: -1 Do you understand the meaning of "like" version? The fact that you ask if it's a personal quirk or habit tells me you do not. Please add the source or share your research so that users don't waste their time explaining something you already know.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, I know that sometimes native speakers use "like" too much. It seems to me as a non-native speaker. Is "What was the weather?" not used in English?

Comment: Look up the meaning of "What is X like?" The X can be any noun or noun phrase.

Comment: *`I know that sometimes native speakers use "like" too much.`* that's when "like" is being used as a filler e.g. "Like do you know what I mean?" "I said like what is that you want?"

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/131949/i-cant-understand-the-meaning-of-she-has-like-10-cars/131951#131951 and https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/312416/you-mean-like-a-therapist/312426#312426

Comment: @Mari-LouA, Your examples are completely about the different meaning of "like". If you can't write the answer, please don't do it. I have an answer from another native speaker: "I don't see any difference, although we'd probably ask "How was the weather?" rather than "What was the weather?" "What was the weather like?" is fine."

Comment: I haven't written an answer. And I don't see any answer on this page. Oh, you mean the comments, so mine are utterly unrelated to your question. I actually provided an example where "What was the show? is grammatical, you must have missed it. And my asking if you understood the meaning of "What was the weather like?" was unnecessary because you *do* know the meaning. You should edit and make this clear in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Mari-Lou A already said something to this effect in the comments, but it deserves to be expanded into a real answer.)

It doesn't make much of a difference when you're asking about the weather, but in other sentences, the "like" can make a big difference in the meaning.

Consider the dialogs:

> "What was the movie?"
> "It was Frankenstein."

and

> "What was the movie like?"
> "It was really scary. I liked it a lot."

For the weather, these two questions are essentially the same; "it rained all the time" is a reasonable answer for both.

Comment: Shor, it's not the best answer because it's a little bit strange to compare movies with weather. Movies have names, but the weather doesn't have it, right? In that case, I don't understand if both sentences mentioned in the post are idiomatic or not.

Comment: @Sergei: They're both idiomatic. And technically, maybe the answer to "what was the weather?" should be "rain", while the answer to "what was the weather like?" should be "wet", but they're essentially asking the same question, so English speakers treat the two sentences the same.